# Apply API data into a dynamical select drop downlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Use API to retrieve the data and then apply it to the dynamic select dropdown list.
The id should be a value and the name should be a label.

Problem:
How do you retrieve and then apply the data into the select dropdown list?

Info:
*I'm new in React JS

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dropdown-sample-thx8xv?file=index.js

Thank you!

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";
import "react-dropdown/style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          users: data
        })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  onSelect(option) {
    console.log("You selected ", option.label);
    console.log("You selected ", option.value);
    //this.setState({selected: option})
  }

  render() {
    const options = [
      { value: "one", label: "One" },
      { value: "two", label: "Two", className: "myOptionClassName" },
      { value: "three", label: "Default" }
    ];

    const defaultOption = options[3];

    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          options={options}
          onChange={o => this.onSelect(o)}
          value={defaultOption}
          placeholder="Select an option"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You should show an example of the API response, if that's what will be used to populate the dropdown.

Comment: "You should show an example of the API response, if"    fetchUsers() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Forked project here :](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dropdown-sample-ffgnzf?file=index.js)

- Move API fetch to [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method
- Initialize `state` as an empty array -> as this is going to be updated as an Array and the initial render would cause no issues with `map` further being used
- Map over list (results after data fetched and updated to state) - [for more info on list building](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and then bind to dropdown

Comment: Thank you for your help! How about the value? The value should be id.

Comment: Hey @What'sUP  my bad didn't observe the dropdown component, i have updated the code do check and please do vote if you found useful thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!